# Tablet won't boot

Tags: software-update

Hello there I was wondering if anyone can help. I have a hipstreet Pilot Tablet. I think it's either got a corrupted OS file that it won't connect to Wi-Fi or boot with saying files are not installed. Is there anyway to go back to a fresh software so no errors in the OS or root files. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a factory reset/ hard reset? If not, follow instructions below:
http://www.hardreset.info/devices/hipstreet/hipstreet-pilot/

Comment: Yes I've done all of that think there's a corrupted file in the OS may need connecting to pc to do it